# Can ScrollTo work on a form page or is there another way?

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, scrollto

I have a scrollTo() on a form page that is not working.  My function takes a string that is an ElementId and should then scroll to that element in this case it is an .  The exact same code and html layout works on another page.  The only difference is that this is on a form page and is wrapped in a . Is there any reason that this should not work?

I have tried removing the div, changing the way I call scrollTo(), such as ngOnInit(), ionViewDidLoad(), from a button, moving the button.

This is my function

```
public scrollTo(elementId: string) {
        console.log("SCROLL TO");
        let y = document.getElementById(elementId).offsetTop;
        this.content.scrollTo(0, y);
    }
```

Expected results - When the function is executed the page scrolls to the specified element.
Actual results - the function executes without error, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo for this? my guess is you are passing id incorrectly.

Comment: The previous page has the same exact elements but the fields are populated instead of being a form eg. One is the details and the other is the form page. Literally copy paste on the scrollTo() code.

Comment: I'm actually not even trying to pass the 'Id'  in at the moment.  I'm hard coding it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `const el = document.getElementById(elementId); el.scrollIntoView(false);` or if you don't have to support IE,  `el.scrollIntoView({ block: 'nearest', inline: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' })` is a better experience.